# r: group, remove columns, and sum

Tags: r, dplyr

I've had some trouble with a large data.frame.  I need to sum each column of groups, if each group column does not have any 0's (complete).  I.E. I only want to sum columns of each group that is "complete".

Here is an example of needing to group and sum each column, however, I cannot figure out how to work `complete.cases` in a dplyr pipeline

```
df <- data.frame(ca = c("a","b","a","c","b"),
             f = c(3,4,0,2,3),
             f2 = c(2,5,6,1,9),
             f3 = c(3,0,6,3,0))
```

What the outcome should look like

```
  ca  f f2 f3
1  a NA  8  9
2  b  7 14 NA
3  c  2  1  3
```

This works to sum each group

```
df2 <- df %>%
    arrange(ca) %>%
    group_by(ca) %>%
    summarize_at(.cols=vars(starts_with("f")),
            .funs=funs("sum"))
```

Here is what I cannot get to work, but it seems like what I should be working towards

```
df2 <- df %>%
    arrange(ca) %>%
    group_by(ca) %>%
    summarize_(funs_(sum(complete.cases(.),na.rm=T)))
```

Maybe I need a `summarize_if`, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one column is grouped, the `*_all` functions will operate on all the non-grouping columns. You can use `na_if` to insert `NA`s for a particular value, which makes the whole process fairly simple:

```
df %>% mutate_all(funs(na_if(., 0L))) %>% 
    group_by(ca) %>%
    summarise_all(sum)

## # A tibble: 3 × 4
##       ca     f    f2    f3
##   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1      a    NA     8     9
## 2      b     7    14    NA
## 3      c     2     1     3
```

or combine the two calls, if you like:

```
df %>% group_by(ca) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(na_if(., 0L))))
```

which returns the same thing.

---

#### Benchmarks

Per the comments, benchmarks on 10000 rows and 100 non-grouping columns. Very wide data (more than 1000 columns) does not fare well with either method, but if you gather to long and group by the former variable names, it's tolerable.

```
library(tidyr)
set.seed(47)

df <- data.frame(ca = sample(letters[1:3], 10000, replace = TRUE), 
                 replicate(100, rpois(100, 10)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    'two stp' = {
        df %>% mutate_all(funs(na_if(., 0L))) %>% 
            group_by(ca) %>% summarise_all(sum)
    }, 'one stp' = {
        df %>% group_by(ca) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(na_if(., 0L))))
    }, 'two stp, reshape' = {
        df %>% gather(var, val, -ca) %>% 
            mutate(val = na_if(val, 0L)) %>% 
            group_by(ca, var) %>% summarise(val = sum(val)) %>% 
            spread(var, val)
    }, 'one stp, reshape' = {
        df %>% gather(var, val, -ca) %>% 
            group_by(ca, var) %>% summarise(val = sum(na_if(val, 0L))) %>% 
            spread(var, val)
    })

## Unit: milliseconds
##              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
##           two stp 311.36733 330.23884 347.77353 340.98458 354.21105 548.4810   100   c
##           one stp 299.90327 317.38300 329.78662 326.66370 341.09945 385.1589   100  b 
##  two stp, reshape  61.72992  67.78778  85.94939  73.37648  81.04525 300.5608   100 a  
##  one stp, reshape  70.95492  77.76685  90.53199  83.33557  90.14023 297.8924   100 a
```

Using `data.table`s via `dtplyr` is much faster. If you don't mind learning another grammar, writing in `data.table` is faster yet (h/t @docendodiscimus for `replace`). Reshaping results in worse times here, at least with `tidyr` functions, though with `data.table::melt` and `dcast` it still may be a good option for extremely wide data.

```
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
set.seed(47)

df <- data.frame(ca = sample(letters[1:3], 10000, replace = TRUE), 
                 replicate(100, rpois(10000, 10)))
setDT(df)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    'dtplyr 2 stp' = {
        df %>% mutate_all(funs(na_if(., 0L))) %>% 
            group_by(ca) %>% 
            summarise_all(sum)
    }, 'dtplyr 1 stp' = {
        df %>% group_by(ca) %>% 
            summarise_all(funs(sum(na_if(., 0L))))
    }, 'dt + na_if 2 stp' = {
        df[, lapply(.SD, function(x){na_if(x, 0L)})][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ca]
    }, 'dt + na_if 1 stp' = {
        df[, lapply(.SD, function(x){sum(na_if(x, 0L))}), by = ca]
    }, 'pure dt 2 stp' = {
        df[, lapply(.SD, function(x){replace(x, x == 0L, NA)})][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ca]
    }, 'pure dt 1 stp' = {
        df[, lapply(.SD, function(x){sum(replace(x, x == 0L, NA))}), by = ca]
    })

## Unit: milliseconds
##              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
##      dtplyr 2 stp 121.31556 130.88189 143.39661 138.32966 146.39086 355.24750   100   c
##      dtplyr 1 stp  28.30813  31.03421  36.94506  33.28435  43.46300  55.36789   100  b 
##  dt + na_if 2 stp  27.03971  29.04306  34.06559  31.20259  36.95895  53.66865   100  b 
##  dt + na_if 1 stp  10.50404  12.64638  16.10507  13.43007  15.18257  34.37919   100 a  
##     pure dt 2 stp  27.15501  28.91975  35.07725  30.28981  33.03950 238.66445   100  b 
##     pure dt 1 stp  10.49617  12.09324  16.31069  12.84595  20.03662  34.44306   100 a
```

Comment: The number of columns is quite long, is there a difference in speed for `mutate_all` first vs combining the two calls?

Comment: Edited with benchmarks. One step will looks to be regularly slightly faster, but using `data.table` even as a backend will make it much faster.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go in base R is to fill the 0s in as NA and then use `aggregate.`

```
# fill 0s as NAs
is.na(df) <- df == 0

aggregate(cbind(f=df$f,f2=df$f2,f3=df$f3), df["ca"], sum)
  ca  f f2 f3
1  a NA  8  9
2  b  7 14 NA
3  c  2  1  3
```

---

*Note:* Using the formula interface to `aggregate` may produce an unexpected result.

```
aggregate(.~ca, data=df, sum)
  ca f f2 f3
1  a 3  2  3
2  c 2  1  3
```

The "b" category drops out and the value for a in variable f is 3, not NA. The specification in the help file indicates that na.action is set to `na.omit`, which drops NA values from computation. To get the formula interface to work as desired, change this value to na.pass.

```
aggregate(.~ca, data=df, sum, na.action=na.pass)
  ca  f f2 f3
1  a NA  8  9
2  b  7 14 NA
3  c  2  1  3
```

Comment: I would use base R, but the grouping function of `dplyr` is why I chose this method.  Is there a `group-by` function in base R that could do the same thing?   I have roughly 45 groups of 5 rows, and ~5,000 columns that vary from group to group.